# Developing a URL Shortener

Tags: django, url, url-shortener

I am trying to develop a URL shortener application for practice with Django. I do not understand how can I create unique strings for each long URL to use as a short URL. Something like other popular URL shorteners do. How can I do this? Is it possible to make all short urls of the same length?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **I do not understand how can I create unique strings for each long URL to use as a short URL. Something like other popular URL shorteners do.**
   *As sugerman has said, this is simple, you just create a hash table.*
2. **How can I do this?**
   *There are dynamic ways to do this, but the simplest and most effective is to have a 2 field table in a database, which holds the hashkey and full url.  Then your server, like Apache, would have the ability to redirect to the correct page.*
3. **Is it possible to make all short urls of the same length?**
   *Yes, to a certain extent, however once you reach the maximum amount of keys, you would have to reuse/replace the short url IDs.  When you set a fixed-length, then you're limiting the amount of possibilities.*

#### My question to you:

I'm under the assumption that by `URL shortener` you are referring to something like jsFiddle or a pastebin in that they have something like `http://jsfiddle.net/sdfj2/`.  Otherwise, we'd need some more clarification.

Comment: The answer mentions a hash table. Given how many URLs there are around, I'd suggest a big hash to avoid collisions (something like SHA512). However, since that wouldn't exactly be short anymore, base64 encode your hashes. It's completely reversible, so getting them back out of the table is a breeze, and it shortens them nicely into a URL-legal character set.

Comment: @peachykeen What about equal lengths?

Comment: instead of using a hash function like md5/sha, it'd be easier to just increment. [0-9a-zA-Z] + any other acceptable characters (eg "-") and just increment your way up the list.  You don't want to use a one-way encryption for the possibility of reusing the same key twice, which could mess things up.  What is more important is your method to keep things short (short is the obvious goal).  jsfiddle adds the non-anonymou username to the url: `jsfiddle.net/user/sdf2s/` and then they follow it up with a numeric count for the revisions.

Comment: @Shubh: an encoded hash automatically has equal lengths. SHA-512 is always 512 bits. As vol7ron noted, there can be collisions, so another technique may be easier. However, with a sufficiently large hash (512 is decently long), you're not going to run into many collisions. It's really a matter of personal preference which you go with.

Comment: -1 because u havent updated your question with with your comments.

Answer (score 9):

You'll probably want to create a simple db table mapping a short value to a URL.

The simplest short url you can generate would just be a serial number or autoincrement column (assign the first value 1, then 2 and so on)

It's possible to make all of the URLs of the same length as long until you don't run out of values of the same length, eg if you were using only numbers (as a simple example) it would be from 0000 to 9999.

The magic part would be where you would use mod_rewrite to pass the url to your script as a parameter, have your application look the value up in the db then redirect the user.

This rewrite rule for mod_rewrite will take a URL like example.com/0000 and redirect to example.com/index.py?id=0000  You would put this in .htaccess (I'm assuming you're using apache.)

Your application just reads the id and redirects to the associated page.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.py?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you decide to go with a hash, or a simple base64 serial number (which would be a more compact autoincrement), it would just look slightly different:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.py?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Heh, that veered quite a bit off topic.  I should have been a university professor. ;)

Comment: +1 for the sequential auto-increment -- also see [this coding horror blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/url-shortening-hashes-in-practice.html)

Comment: And well, with Django, you most probably shouldn't use mod_rewrite - just put everything through Django and use urls.py rules to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the blog post linked above. basically, how I did it was as follows:

Store the long url in a table with an auto-incrementing index field. Retrieve the index. Convert it to a string, the same way you would convert it to say, a hexadecimal or octal number, but using all available characters as possible "digits". For example, say we have a-z, A-Z, and 0-9 available, do the following:

0 = 0
1 = 1
...
9 = 9
10 = a
11 = b
...
35 = z
36 = A
37 = B
...
60 = Z
61 = 10
62 = 11
...
70 = 19
71 = 1a
72 = 1b

You get the pattern? It's a generic conversion algorithm from a base-10 number to a base-n number, where n is the number of characters to your disposal.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to want to set up a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to generate the shortened URL.

**Edit:**

Rather than sit here and summarize a pretty detailed Wikipedia article for you, [here's a link](http://www.wewillraakyou.com/2010/10/how-do-url-shorteners-work/) to a blog post explaining how hash functions work in relation to your exact topic (URL shorteners).

Comment: -1 - don't just post links to blogs, always give brief explanation with that. Quite often links break and then your answer is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Check [django-shorturls](http://github.com/jacobian/django-shorturls) app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it: https://github.com/bitmazk/django-tinylinks
One client is using this in production since one year.